# NetBeans IDE 8.0 with Ivy

Tags: netbeans, ivy

While migrating from Eclipse (Kepler) to Netbeans 8.0, I am facing some road blocks with Ivy. 
I could install Ivy plugin in Netbeans but I have some questions:

1. In Eclipse, we can setup Ivy settings. I don't see that in NetBeans.
2. I also don't see how to resolve ivy dependencies in NetBeans. I don't see any right click options.

Why there is no documentation on NetBeans 8.0 with Ivy???

Comment: Hello Sujoy, any luck so far ? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Nope...The plugin I imported didn't work. And I don't see any other ivy plugin for NetBeans in market. Strange...may be it's time to write one.

Comment: That's a shame. I really don't want to move to Eclipse :-). But ...

Comment: Why don't you use Maven? Maven works like a charm with NetBeans and not so good with Eclipse. My problem is my firm doesn't want to use Maven. I guess, that's your problem too.

Comment: Thats not possible, it's big piece of corporate software which is build by Ant. We are developing custom components using maven, but there is no chance to switch completely to Maven.

Comment: There's a SBT plugin which allows running Ant targets.
https://github.com/sbt/ant4sbt